# Why is ym-faux-ad-iframe being injected into my DOM?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a very basic skeleton React project set up.

Created using create-react-app using react-scripts-ts for typescript support. I have added on redux, and react-router. However, I just noticed that there is an iframe that is being injected into my DOM at some point and I cannot figure out why or where it is coming from.

It appears to be some sort of amazon ad iframe.

This is the request made by the browser

```
curl 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/ym-hosting/faux-ad.htm?advertiserId=78946&brandName=faux' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Pragma: no-cache' -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Referer: http://localhost:3000/' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --compressed
```

Installed Dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^16.6.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.6.0",
  "react-redux": "^5.1.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
  "react-scripts-ts": "3.1.0",
  "redux": "^4.0.1",
  "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
  "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/jest": "^23.3.9",
  "@types/node": "^10.12.2",
  "@types/react": "^16.4.18",
  "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.9",
  "@types/react-redux": "^6.0.9",
  "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
  "@types/redux": "^3.6.0",
  "@types/redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
  "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
  "@types/redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
  "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.5",
  "typescript": "^3.1.6"
},
```

Has anyone else seen anything like this before? Is some module quietly injecting this to cash in on easy ad views?

Screenshots:

[Network Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/031wI.png)
[DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXLFj.png)

**EDIT: Turns out this has nothing to do with React or create-react-app but with a browser extension "HoverZoom".**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe it's a React problem, I think it must be a browser extension injecting the iframe. I recently started developing a web app of my own (using F# on ASP.NET Core) and saw the same thing in my app's DOM just yesterday; your question was the only thing that came up when I googled around, so I thought to check other sites and everywhere I go seems to have it.

The iframe doesn't appear to be malicious at first glance (it's a faux ad for a Santa Fe getaway), but who knows if there's tracking code on the other end following our movements. Now to start disabling extensions until I find the culprit...

Edit: Appears to be Hover Zoom? Not sure if you use that one, but disabling it removed the iframe for me, so now it's gone forever.

Comment: Hmm, I am using hover zoom. It's weird though, because I have been using it for a while now and have done plenty of development on this machine and I don't think I've ever noticed it before. I wonder if there was an update recently that added it?

Comment: Same code injected in my code and I am using PHP and Materialize framework for my website. Thefeore I agree with user1968292 that it must be a browser extension that inserts the tracker (More specifically a Chrome browser extension because I don't see it when I use FireFox).

Comment: I had the same thing using the SpeakIt! extension on Chrome.